# Labelling Axes in Visual Studio Graphs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have tried using the instruction:

```
Graph1.Series("Series1").Points(1).AxisLabel = "X Axis Label"
```

to label the X axis on a graph.
A similar instruction should apply to the Y axis.

Unfortunately, the instruction produces the following error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

What's *wrong* with my instruction?
How do I deal with the error?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add titles to the axis you need to modify the ChartArea not the Series.

The Series represents the data points used by the chart, but you can use this to set an axis label for the entire series or individual points.

It looks like your error is due to having no data points in the table series.

Here's the difference between the two:

```
    Chart1.Series("Series1").AxisLabel = "Series Label"
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points(0).AxisLabel = "Point Label"

    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Title = "Chart Area X Axis Label"
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Title = "Chart Area Y Axis Label"
```

[image: Chart with labelled axis]